# OSX: app to intercept the "close" command

Tags: macos, bash, shell, applescript

Quick background: new mac, long time windows user; not scared by linux and scripts; not a native english speaker, so be nice with my translation :)

I am currently using [RedQuits](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39814/redquits) to make the x red button quit de app, not just close the window.

It is a great program, but has one small problem (for me): one can not select which apps should maintain the default behavior (x close the window, not the app).

So i found a very old (2006) app called [Stoplight](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/26669-stoplight-11-released/) that does exactly what i want: select which programs should not be affected.

Unfortunately, Stoplight does not work anymore.

So, i tried to see what the script does (it's a .bundle), but looks like it's compiled.

To the questions:

- is there a way to decompile the script, so i can make it work again?
- if not, anyone have an idea about how to make a whitelist of apps that should not be closed by RedQuits?
- again, if not, where should i start to build my own script to intercept the signal that closes the windows and make it kill the app?
- any other hints are appreciated.

Thanks.

---

EDIT (2013-09-23)

I have found a workaround for my problem.
I created an AppleScript to monitor for processes running in the background that do not have a window.
If the process is not in the whitelist, close it.

I will post the script later, but to tell the truth, i dont like my solution and still want to know if you guys have any ideas.

So i will not accept my answer as the right one.

---

EDIT (2013-09-26)

Should we migrate the question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: just curious, why do you want to quit the apps?

Comment: @nielsbot personal preference. thats all. :)

Comment: "Why?" How can someone even ask :) Ofc you dont want to quit it - since you dont care if it runs or not. But you 120% want to quit that stupid top panel which stays open when app is not quit. In case u ask why: 1. you dont want to switch windows (cmd+tab) to dead app like that, it has no use for you 2. if you accidantely switch to it, you are not aware of it cause you see for example internet browser which is opened below it and you dont notice small change in top left label. 3. how is it different from minimizing the app?? Real question is: why would anyone want to keep that app opened.

Comment: @jsherk WHat version of OS do you use? I have 10.10 and redquits doesnt work for me :( even when I set up the permissions for accessibility and everything - it still doesnt work for me :/

Comment: @user1096901 I posted my original comment back in 2013 but since that time I have stopped using RedQuits because, as you said, it stopped working in newer versions of OSX. Instead I have now switched to Better Touch Tool which allows you to setup either global triggers/shortcuts or application specific ones. I setup the following two global triggers/actions (and no longer use the red button):
trigger= Doubleclick Main Menubar = action= Command+Q ..... 
trigger= Leftclick Green Window Button = action= Maximize Window

Comment: @user1096901 - its been a long time, and my script has changed a little bit, but i still use it to close apps that are not running for X minutes. dont be scared by the negative score, it works.

Comment: @jsherk - its been a long time, and my script has changed a little bit, but i still use it to close apps that are not running for X minutes. dont be scared by the negative score, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my workaround. I'm not happy with it, since it loops every 10 seconds to "quit" processes.
Posting it here just in case it helps anyone out there...

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

-- INICIO DAS FUNCOES EXTRAS
set app_path to path to current application
set app_name to get name of me
set myPath to path to me
tell application "Finder" to set myFolder to (container of myPath) as string
set commonScript to load script alias ((myFolder) & "FuncoesExtras.scpt")
-- FIM DAS FUNCOES EXTRAS

set WhiteList to {app_name, "App Store", "iTunes", "Finder", "Mail"}

repeat

    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with this_app in (get processes whose background only is false and windows is {})
            set NomeDoApp to the name of this_app
            if NomeDoApp is not in WhiteList then
                try
                    tell NomeDoApp to quit
                    log_event("App " & NomeDoApp & " encerrado com sucesso", "FecharProgramas") of commonScript
                on error
                    do shell script "killall " & quoted form of NomeDoApp
                    log_event("Forcando interrupcao do App " & NomeDoApp, "FecharProgramas") of commonScript
                end try
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell

    tell application "System Events" to set myPID to (unix id of processes whose name is app_name)
    do shell script ("/usr/bin/renice 18 " & myPID)

    delay 10

end repeat
```

I'm still open to suggestions.

Comment: two years later, someone finds the time to downvote a correct answer. wow.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not quite what you want to hear, but you can do this with the CMD-Q keyboard shortcut.

However if you need to filter which applications this works for you could do it with a keyboard shortcut this way:

- New Service in the Automator application
- Add a "Run Applescript" action
- Set the service parameters:

Service receives `no input` in `any application`

- Add the following Applescript:

.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to quit
    return input
end run
```

- Save the service with a new name, e.g. QuitAll, and close the automator app
- Open the "Keyboard" section of the "System Preferences" dialog
- Select the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab
- Select "Services" from the left-hand side
- Scroll down the right-hand side to find your "QuitAll" service
- Enable and click the right-hand side of the "QuitAll" service
- Add a keyboard shortcut.  I choose CTRL-CMD-Q, but you can choose whatever
- Close the Keyboard preferences dialog

Now this is very bare bones - it *should* work for *all* apps, with no exceptions, just like CMD-Q.  You should be able to edit the applescript to add some sort of app filtering here.

Comment: +1 nice - but for me for a different reason :)) namely how to connect the dots between automator + script + kybd shortcut.  I've looked for this kind of combination many times but never found it - probably searched the wrong way. Links to docs you have found useful re this theme would be great.

Comment: @HowardPautz - I googled `automator service keyboard shortcut`.  There are several useful results; in particular I thought [this tutorial](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tips-shortcuts/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/) captured the workflow in a pretty straightforward way.

Comment: @HowardPautz - and to keep it in the StackExchange family there is [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43998/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-service-in-os-x)

Comment: thx - hey! I remember reading that tutorial :)) For me, it was the parms of the apple script (which that tut doesn't use) that your answer filled in as the missing link so to say. Now lets see if I can get it to run a slew of bash scripts :))